# How to retrieve Nodejs/Express web server port number from a loaded-in-browser Javascript file

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, port

My situation is the following:
I have a Node/Express server.js file which gets run by Node.js. This backend is for my website, which I deploy to Heroku. The webserver serves two endpoints, from either const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000:

- '/', or root (this responds by sending file index.html)
- '/transcription'

When a request is made to /transcription, an Axios post request is made to a third-party API to get a temporary token. This token is passed into the response from /transcription as res.json(data). No problems so far.

The trickiness enters here. I have JavaScript file, asr.js, which is loaded when I visit page asr.html (different from index.html). In asr.js, I fetch http://localhost:8000/transcription. Now, this works locally for me; I get my temporary token and continue with my transcription. However, when I push this to an environment like Heroku, where I don't know what the port number is going to be, I cannot successfully make that fetch request to neither http://localhost:8000/transcription nor http://localhost:${PORT}/transcription because `process` is not defined in my asr.js file; it's not being executed by node.

So, the question I have is *how can I determine what my Node/Express server port is when I deploy my app to Heroku such that I can use it in asr.js when I visit asr.html?*

Or maybe that's not the right question to be asking? Community, please help!

Here is a snapshot of my folder hierarchy, for more context. Let me know if more information is required or if my initial explanation is not enough.

[image]

To be clear, I use middleware to statically serve the **public** folder.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something here, why would you need the port in production?

Very rarely is node run as the webserver, typically you will have NGINX proxy the request to the backend server so that port is only valid to the NGINX server to proxy those request back to node, otherwise your app would not work with a TLD without the port.

Long story short, your frontend JS should not need the port number and be able to just use the TLD running on port 80 / 443